# Does the build automation tool in Gradle replace the apk file every time I hit the "run" Button?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Does gradle always replace the apk file every time I press compile and run?
In which cases it does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Creates build every time if that have major changes of resources, or the file app-debug.apk does not exists, So if you want to create a fresh apk file then rename the older apk. If runs the same code multiple times new apk does not created.